# hibernate mapping for list of classes

Tags: hibernate

I have a class A{a_id,other properties List) and class B{b_id,other properties).
I have different tables for A and B and mapping table A_B(a_id,b_id,displayorder).Entries in table are constant . We can insert/update/delete from table A. I try to map it in hibernate using list but it is not inserting any row in A_B. What should be the ideal way to map above scenario.

```
<class name="A" table="A"> 
    <id name="templateKey" column="templateKey"> 
        <generator class="native" /> 
     </id> 
    <property name="id" column="id"/> 
    <property name="name" column="name"/> 
    <list name="selectedColumns" table="A_B"> 
        <key column="templateKey"/> 
        <list-index column="displayOrder"/> 
        <one-to-many class="B" /> 
    </list> 
</class> 
<class name="B" table="B"> 
    <id name="columnKey" column="columnKey"> 
        <generator class="native" /> 
    </id> 
    <property name="displayName" column="displayName" /> 
</class>
```

Comment: show the code for your hbm files.

Comment: `code`<class name="A" table="A">
   <id name="templateKey" column="templateKey">
     <generator class="native" />
   </id>
   <property name="id" column="id"/>
   <property name="name" column="name"/>
   <list name="selectedColumns" table="A_B">
      <key column="templateKey"/>
      <list-index column="displayOrder"/>
      <one-to-many class="B"  />
      </list>
</class>
<class name="B" table="B">
   <id name="columnKey" column="columnKey">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
   <property name="displayName" column="displayName" />
</class>`code`

Answer (score 1):

change your hbm file for A like this. 
You missed **Cascade** in A's hbm file which is why I suspect its no inserting in A_B.

```
<class name="A" table="A">
        <id name="templateKey" column="templateKey">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="id" column="id" />
        <property name="name" column="name" />
        <list name="selectedColumns" table="A_B" cascade="all">
            <key column="templateKey" />
            <list-index column="displayOrder" />
            <one-to-many class="B" />
        </list>
    </class>
```